# How to find minimum n for Composite Trapezoidal rule?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm taking a course on numerical methods to be able to program math, it's part of the game option of my compsci bachelors.This is part of one of the questions:

> Given the integral: $\int_6^{12} (9x^3 - x^4)dx$
>
> A. Using the Composite Trapezoidal Rule, what is the min. n required to have an accuracy of six decimal places (TOL. $\le 10^{-6}$), in the approximation of the given integral. n must be solved theoretically.
>
> B. just use the composite trapezoidal rule with said n, which is easy since I programmed the rule (code here: http://pastebin.com/QzRdijrh)
>
> C. Same as A but for Composite Simpson's rule.
>
> D. Same as B but for Composite Simpson's rule (code here: http://pastebin.com/V9DYdRXU)

So the problem I'm having is I can't remember how to find minimum n, I know for Bisection Algorithm you make $2^n \le (b-a)/TOL$ But I forgot how to apply that to other rules...

Answer (score 2):

The error term of the composite trapezoidal rule is $\frac {(b-a)^3}{12n^2}f''(\xi)$ so you need to evaluate the second derivative of your function, find its maximum and plug everything in.  You will get something like error $\lt \frac a{n^2}$.  Then you choose $n$ to get the error lower than $10^{-6}$.  For the composite Simpson's rule, the approach is the same, but you have a different expression for the error.

Comment: The reason we ignore the error term is we're given no value of z (the number plugged into the 3rd derivative). But basically to get min n for any of these it's $error term \ge TOL$? I'm just trying to figure out a way to generalize it because I can't seem to find it in any of my notes and I copy everything off the board word for word.

Comment: @Portaljacker:  you can find the maximum of the second derivative over your interval.  The derivative is $54x-12x^2$, which has maximum absolute value at $x=12$ of 1080, so you can use that for the second derivative term.  The real error will be less.